# Laravel 8 - How do I redirect /{editable_text} route to /{user} route

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, laravel-8

I've been trying to create redirect route that will lead me to user profile. Redirect route should be string/text from database of user and it should redirect to that same users profile page.

For example lets say my user1 has column named "editable_link" with value of "abcd123" and profile which is accessible with route "www.mywebsite.com/user1", so when someone goes to "www.mywebsite.com/abcd123" it should redirect him to "www.mywebsite.com/user1".

I have tried many approaches but nothing worked for me since I am new to coding. Can someone give me some of the best solutions for this?

This is what I have in my web.php:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Http\Controllers\UserController;
use App\Http\Controllers\VisitController;
use App\Http\Controllers\LinkController;
use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Verified;

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
Route::get('/verified', function () {
    return view('verified');
});

Auth::routes(['verify' => true]);

Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth', 'prefix' => 'dashboard', ], function() {

    Route::get('/links', [LinkController::class, 'index']);
    Route::get('/links/new', [LinkController::class, 'create'])->middleware('verified');
    Route::post('/links/new', [LinkController::class, 'store']);
    Route::get('/links/{link}', [LinkController::class, 'edit']);
    Route::post('/links/{link}', [LinkController::class, 'update']);
    Route::delete('/links/{link}', [LinkController::class, 'destroy']);
    Route::get('/qr', [LinkController::class, 'qr']);

    Route::get('/settings', [UserController::class, 'settings']);
    Route::get('/settings/edit', [UserController::class, 'edit']);
    Route::get('/settings/profile', [UserController::class, 'profile']);
    Route::get('/settings/help', [UserController::class, 'help']);
    Route::post('/settings/edit', [UserController::class, 'update']);
    Route::post('/settings/profile', [UserController::class, 'update_avatar']);

});

Route::post('/visit/{link}', [VisitController::class, 'store']);
Route::get('/{user}', [UserController::class, 'show'])->name('show');
```

This is what I had in mind to create:

```
Route::get('/qr/{editable_link}', function () {
    return redirect('{user}');
Route::get('/{user}', [UserController::class, 'show'])->name('show');
});
```

I can post any other code you need, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check first if the route which contains an editable_link value does exist in database. Then so you can't do that inside the route definition since the database is not ready there yet.

Your option to check the existence is through of course a place where database is usable, such as in controller or middleware.

Let the route be only this one

```
Route::get('/{user}', [UserController::class, 'show'])->name('show');
```

Then inside the `UserController` `show` method, you have to create condition such as, example

```
public function show($user)
{
    // checks if $user parameter is an editable_link that exist in db
    $userWithEditableLink = User::where('editable_link', $user)->first();
    
    // redirect if above exist to the same route but with, for example, username
    if ($userWithEditableLink) {
        return redirect($userWithEditableLink->username);
    }
    
    // do something as, such as
    // $user = User::where('username', $user)->firstOrFail();
}
```

Or, you may create a middleware which contains such above condition also.

Comment: I will try this and let you know, thank you for your help.

Comment: Hey, I added your code but nothing happens, maybe I didn't do it as I should. This is my UserController public function show, it has some other stuff in it so it may cause some problems?